# Echo output from many PostgreSQL files

Tags: linux, bash, postgresql, shell, command-line

I am using PostgreSQL 9.5 on Fedora 24.

I've got the following files:

```
 $ cat hello.sql
SELECT 'hello';
 $ cat world.sql
SELECT 'world';
```

And there are two executions below:

```
 $ psql samples -f hello.sql -f world.sql
 ?column? 
----------
 world
(1 row)

 $ psql samples -f world.sql -f hello.sql
 ?column? 
----------
 hello
(1 row)
```

What should I do to see output from both scripts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mistake in my understanding was trying execute many PostgreSQL files in a single command. I should rather use the following bash script:

```
 $ cat hello_world.sh
SQL_FILES=(hello.sql world.sql)
for SQL_FILE in ${SQL_FILES[@]}
do
    psql samples -f $SQL_FILE
done
```

The execution below is exactly what I need:

```
 $ ./hello_world.sh
 ?column? 
----------
 hello
(1 row)

 ?column? 
----------
 world
(1 row)
```

Answer (score 3):

Or you could just:

```
$ cat hello.sql world.sql |psql -f -
 ?column?
----------
 hello
(1 row)

 ?column?
----------
 world
(1 row)
```

Comment: this command not working in my env.  postgres@host:~$  cat hello.sql world.sql |psql -f -
psql:<stdin>:2: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "select"
LINE 2: select 'world' what is the reason?

Comment: You have ";"s in place?

Answer (score 0):

you can use as below;

```
for sqlfile in hello.sql world.sql; do psql samples -f "$sqlfile"; done
```

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what I meant in my answer.